# Button em cima de uma View com Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, view

Estou tentando a algum tempo já colocar um Button em cima de uma View que estou utilizando com o Canvas. Procurei em vários lugares (este parece ser um problema comum) mais não achei resposta.

Quando tento rodar o programa abaixo, dá o erro:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.View cannot be cast to com.examples.danilofernandes.canvasonrelativelayout.RandomShapeView
```

Alguma ideia de como fazer o que preciso?

Muito obrigado

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

private RandomShapeView mDrawingArea;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    mDrawingArea = (RandomShapeView) findViewById(R.id.drawing_area);
    mDrawingArea.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

}

}
```

Outra classe

```
public class RandomShapeView extends View {

Paint paint;

public RandomShapeView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

}

}
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<View
    class="com.examples.danilofernandes.canvasonrelativelayout.RandomShapeView"
    android:id="@+id/drawing_area"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troque o `<View>` por `<com.examples.danilofernandes.canvasonrelativelayout.RandomShapeView>` no arquivo XML do seu layout.

Comment: Valeu, deu certo. Só faltou implementar um construtor, que é exatamente o que foi falado neste tópico. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352249/error-in-creation-of-custom-view